# solving diophantine equations using modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory

Find all positive integers $n$ an primes $p$ such that $$\frac{n^p+1}{p^n+1}$$ is an integer
Let us consider the case $n>p>3$. Now as we know that $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is a decreasing function for $n\geq 3$ so for $n>p>3$ we have $$n^{\frac{1}{n}}<p^{\frac{1}{p}} \implies n^p<p^n \implies n^p+1<p^n+1$$ so no solutions in this case.
So we must have either $p = 2$ or $n \leq p$
The case $p=2$ implies $2^n+1$ divides $n^2+1$ giving $n=2, 4$ and $n=p$ gives $(p,p)$ as a solution where 
$p$ is any prime
So let us consider the case $n < p$, now it is easy to see that $n$ is odd so $p^n+1$ is divisible by $p+1$ so let $q$ be a prime factor of $p+1$ then $q$ divides $p^n+1$ and $q$ divides $n^p+1$ 
Now let $x$ be the smallest number such that $$n^x \equiv -1 modq$$ and $y$ be the smallest number such that $$n^y \equiv 1 modq$$. 
It is easy to see that both $x$ and $y$ exists as $$n^p \equiv -1 modq$$ and $$n^{q-1} \equiv 1 modq \implies y<q$$ 
And we have clearly $x<y$ because if $x>y$ then $x=qy+r$ and so $$-1 \equiv n^x=n^{qy+r}\equiv n^r modq$$ contradicting the minimality of $x$ because $r<x$ 
So $x<y<q<p$ as $q$ divides $p+1$ and $q$ cannot equal $p+1$ or $p$ so $q<p$
Now as $p>x$ so  let $p=sx+t$ with $0<t<x$ so we get $$-1 \equiv n^p=n^{sx+t} \equiv (-1)^sn^t modq$$
So $s$ cannot be even because that will imply $n^t \equiv -1 modq$ contradicting the minimality of $x$ so $s$ must be odd but then we will get $n^t \equiv 1 modq$ contradicting the minimality of $y$ so we get $s=0$ and so $x$ divides $p$ and as $p$ is a prime so $x=p$ but as shown above $x<p$ a contradiction so no solutions in this case
Is my solution correct?